# Why are newer languages able to show better and more precise error messages?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, compiler-errors

Why and how are languages such as Python or Java able to show precise and easy to understand error messages, while the true and tested long-standing C/C++ compilers show cryptic, and often unrelated, error messages?

Comment: CPython's error reporting for syntax errors sucks, and Clang does *very* good error reporting.

Answer (score 5):

**It's not the language; it's the age of the compiler.** Since the late 1970s when Unix started getting into universities, C has been a *de facto* standard.  The market penetration of Microsoft Windows only reinforced this standard.  Because C was the standard, nobody had to write a nice compiler to get people to use it.  And on 1970s and 1980s machines, producing nice error messages took time and space that were perceived as valuable resources.  People were damned happy to get a free C compiler even if the error messages were awful.

The error messages from old C compilers are so bad that there are jokes about them; this is from Chapter 2 of the *Unix Haters' Handbook*:

> Ken Thompson has an automobile which he helped design. Unlike
>   most automobiles, it has neither speedometer, nor gas gauge, nor
>   any of the other numerous idiot lights which plague the modern
>   driver. Rather, if the driver makes a mistake, a giant “?” lights up in
>   the center of the dashboard. “The experienced driver,” says Thompson,
>   “will usually know what’s wrong.”

By the 1990s, when newer languages were spreading, machines were faster and had more memory, and providing good error messages was one way to improve mindshare.

If you try a relatively young C compiler, like [clang](http://clang.llvm.org), you'll find it produces excellent error messages—sometimes even including highlighting and color.  (I bet the error messages from Visual Studio are pretty good too, but I don't know for sure.)

Answer (score 1):

**Compile time errors**

Compile-time errors are cryptic usually thanks to conditional compilation (preprocessor, macros) together with very powerful templates (much more generic than in e.g. C# or Java).

However, it all depends on compiler, e.g. newer CLang claims much more readable error messages.

In my opinion, development is sequential, and line number for error is usually enough (I don't really need to read the error message).

**Runtime errors**

**Performance:** C/C++ has "zero-overhead" goal, so e.g. function names are stripped, functions are inlined. And many errors are "undefined behavior" to allow for faster implementations. It also allows you to do practically anything - even the dangerous operations - unchecked.

**Not really:** many C++ compilers can produce stack-trace on exception.

Comment: I think he was talking about compilation errors, not runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might be possible because of applying additional constraints on programming style/possibilities/syntax etc (this is quite tough to do with old languages such as C/C++ because of need in backward compatibility). E.g. tougher constraints minimize potential error types number and therefore simplify precise errors detection.